# How to make NSTextField only editable if exactly one item is selected in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, nstextfield

In a master-detail application, my master table view allows multiple selections. I use NSArrayController to populate the table view.

I want the text fields in the detail view only be editable, when exactly **one** item in the master table view is selected.

Disabling "*Allows Editing Multiple Values Selection*" in the text field's binding is not enough, because it only disables editing, when the multiple selected items have different values. I want editing disabled always, as soon as more than one item is selected.

Is this achievable from within interface builder?

Comment: Are you using ``NSArrayController`` to populate the table views?

Comment: Yes, i use `NSArrayController`.

Comment: @PaulPatterson Ok, are you alluding to `NSArrayController`'s `alwaysUsesMultipleValuesMarker`. This seems to solve my problem. If that's what you meant, do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Actually I wasn't going to suggest that route - it had never occurred to me. I wanted to know if an ``NSArrayController`` was involved because another option is to base the text fields' editable status on the  status of the ``selectionIndexes`` index set maintained by this object (see my answer). If you decide to use your approach, you should probably write it up as an answer, and then accept  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that a combination of

1. Selecting "Always Use Multi Value Marker" on the `NSArrayController` and

[image]

2. Deselecting "Allows Editing Multiple Value Selection" on the `NSTextField`'s value binding

[image]

results in the behaviour I was looking for.

Comment: This is a really great answer with screen shots from XCode - very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to bind the *Editable* state of your `NSTextField` instances to the `selectionIndexes` property of your `NSArrayController`, then to use a custom value transformer to convert the associated `NSIndexSet` to a boolean whose value is determined by the number of indexes in the index set.

The *Interface Builder* set-up would look like this:

[image]

The value transformer subclass would look like this:

```
@objc(PPSelectionIndexesCountIsExactlyOneTransformer)
public class PPSelectionIndexesCountIsExactlyOneTransformer: NSValueTransformer {

    override public class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override public class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSNumber.self
    }

    override public func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        var retval: AnyObject?
        if let indexSet = value as? NSIndexSet {
            retval = NSNumber(bool: indexSet.count == 1)
        }

        return retval
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well. I also added the other solution I found as an answer. BTW, what software did you use for the nice paper-tear-effect on your screenshot?

Comment: It's called *Snagit* - developed by *TechSmith*.